# How to recursively transform an array of nested objects into array of flat objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of deeply nested objects:

```
const data = [
    {
      name: "foo",
      children:[
        {
          count: 1,
          name: "A"
        },
        { 
          count: 2,
          name: "B"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "bar",
      children: [
        {
          count: 3,
          name: "C",
          children: [
            {
              count: 4,
              name: "D"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

The way I'd like to transform this would be such as:

```
const expectedStructure = [
    {
      count: 1,
      name: "A",
      label: "foo = A"
    },
    {
      count: 2,
      name: "B",
      label: "foo = B"
    },
    {
      count: 3,
      name: "C",
      label: "bar = C"
    },
    {
      count: 4,
      name: "D",
      label: "bar = D"
    }
  ]
```

I created recursive function that transforms nested array into array of flat objects.

Here's my code:

```
function getChildren(array, result=[]) {
    array.forEach(({children, ...rest}) => {
        result.push(rest);
        if(children) {
            getChildren(children, result);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

And here's output I get:

```
[ { name: 'foo' },
  { count: 1, name: 'A' },
  { count: 2, name: 'B' },
  { name: 'bar' },
  { count: 3, name: 'C' },
  { count: 4, name: 'D' } ]
```

The problem is that I need to add `label` field to every object in my output array, and I can't find a solution without iterating multiple times through the final array to make desired transformation. How to properly insert `label` field without hugely augmenting complexity of the function?

Comment: You need to do the recursion differently for the top level and nested levels, because the top-level `name` properties get passed down to all levels below it for the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different function for the nested levels, so you can pass the top-level `name` properties down through all those recursion levels.

```js
function getTopChildren(array, result = []) {
  array.forEach(({
    name,
    children
  }) => {
    if (children) {
      getChildren(children, name, result);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

function getChildren(array, name, result) {
  array.forEach(({
    children,
    ...rest
  }) => {
    rest.label = `${name} = ${rest.name}`;
    result.push(rest);
    if (children) {
      getChildren(children, name, result);
    }
  });
}

const data = [{
    name: "foo",
    children: [{
        count: 1,
        name: "A"
      },
      {
        count: 2,
        name: "B"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    children: [{
      count: 3,
      name: "C",
      children: [{
        count: 4,
        name: "D"
      }]
    }]
  }
]

console.log(getTopChildren(data));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check each iteration whether the current item is a "parent" item, and reassign `label` if it is.

```js
const data = [{name:"foo",children:[{count:1,name:"A"},{count:2,name:"B"}]},{name:"bar",children:[{count:3,name:"C",children:[{count:4,name:"D"}]}]}];

function getChildren(array, result = [], label = "") {
  array.forEach(({ children, name, count }) => {
    if (!label || name[1]) {
      label = `${name} = `;
    }
    if (count) {
      result.push({ count, name, label: label + name });
    }
    if (children) {
      getChildren(children, result, label);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

const res = getChildren(data);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this recursively with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) based on whether or not a `parent` has been passed into the recursive call :

```js
const data = [{
    name: "foo",
    children: [{
        count: 1,
        name: "A"
      },
      {
        count: 2,
        name: "B"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    children: [{
      count: 3,
      name: "C",
      children: [{
        count: 4,
        name: "D"
      }]
    }]
  }
];

function flatten(arr, parent = null) {
  return parent
    ? arr.flatMap(({name, count, children}) => [
        {name, count, label: `${parent} = ${name}`}, 
        ...flatten(children || [], parent)
      ]) 
    : arr.flatMap(({name, children}) => flatten(children || [], name));
}

console.log(flatten(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's a little easier to reason about the code and write it clearly using generators. You can `yield*` from the recursive calls:

```js
const data = [{name: "foo",children:[{count: 1,name: "A"},{ count: 2,name: "B"}]},{name: "bar",children: [{count: 3,name: "C",children: [{count: 4,name: "D"}]}]}]

function* flat(input, n){
    if (!input) return
    if (Array.isArray(input)) {
        for (let item of input)
            yield* flat(item, n)
    }
    let _name = n || input.name

    if ('count' in input) {
        yield { count:input.count, name:input.name, label:`${_name} = ${input.name}`} 
    }
    yield* flat(input.children, _name)
    
}

let g = [...flat(data)]
console.log(g)
```

The function returns a generator, so you need to spread it into a list `[...flat(data)]` if you want a list or iterate over it if you don't need to store the list.