# How to flatten object of objects recursively into array

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
const myObj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1,
      d: 2
    },
    f: {
      z: 4,
      u: 6
    }
  }
}
```

into this:

```
const myObj = [
  {
    c: 1,
    d: 2,
  },
  {
    z: 4,
    u: 6,
  }
]
```

I found this: [How to recursively transform an array of nested objects into array of flat objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57300732/how-to-recursively-transform-an-array-of-nested-objects-into-array-of-flat-objec) but the original is an array of objects, and mine is an object itself.

Comment: What is the exact criteria for flattening?

Comment: what if a value and an object is in an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse the values of the objects until you reach the leaves (objects with no values that are other objects).

```js
const myObj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1,
      d: 2
    },
    f: {
      z: 4,
      u: 6
    }
  }
};
const flatObj = o => Object.values(o).some(x => x === Object(x)) ?
  Object.values(o).flatMap(flatObj) : [o];
console.log(flatObj(myObj))
```